# Designing databases on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I want to ask that is it possible to design databases using SQL Server ?
Is there any external tool required to use with SQL Server or can be done in itself ?

Comment: You can design a database with paper and a pencil ... no high-tech tools needed, really.

Comment: @marc_s While working in a professional corporate environment, they don't wanna see the work on a paper with a pencil. So, any suggestion according to that would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, SQL Server *does* have some very limited tools - like the database diagrams and table designer. But that's by no means a real, professional-grade database design tool. So if you can't live with pencil and paper, I would think the very limited tools built into SQL Server are probably not good enough for your corporate environment, either.

Comment: If you need a full-blown, professional enterprise grade database design tool - like at products like [CA ERWin](http://erwin.com/products/detail/ca_erwin_data_modeler_standard_edition/) or [Sybase PowerDesigner](http://www.sybase.com/products/modelingdevelopment/powerdesigner). Those are pretty $$$$$$ though....

Comment: Visio always works nice for ERDs

Comment: For ER Diagrams you can have 'visio'. 'DBDesigner' if you think you need a prototype, but as @marc_s said a pencil and paper is enough to outline the structure of the database, that should be the starting point. And say you want to show your design you can create the table and have a database diagram generated from SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 4):

Unless I am completely not understanding what you are asking.  You can use [SQL Server Management Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174173.aspx) to design databases.

Answer (score 0):

You need a tool like DBDesigner. Check it out > http://www.fabforce.net/dbdesigner4/screenshots.php

Answer (score 0):

I would put more emphasis on the long term implications of database design, having to maintain the design over time. I would look for a tool that can compare the schema that should be on the live system, with the schema that is really on the live system (as a rule, in a corporate environment, they are never the same). Maybe something like [Altova DatabaseSpy](http://www.altova.com/databasespy.html).